# Ignoring first n digits when importing data from .dat file into matlab

Tags: matlab, import

I want to import data from .dat file into matlab workspace;however i don't want the first 5 digits.

```
34826
-82.7553 -18.7702 -2292.59,
-83.7271 -19.3224 -2291.53,
```

How can i do that? actually i came to the solution of removing those 5 digits from .dat file, but there must be an automatic way for that

my code is like this

```
fileID = fopen('temp.dat');
C = textscan(fileID,'%f %f %f','Delimiter',',');
fclose(fileID);
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip the first lines of the file you import using the 'HeaderLines' option of textscan, followed by the number of rows to skip.

```
nRowsToSkip = 1;
C = textscan(fileID, '%f %f %f','Delimiter',',', 'HeaderLines',nRowsToSkip);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what if it was more than one row? ( two of these in separate lines in the top of data)

Comment: you can specify the number of rows to skip after 'HeaderLines'For example to skip 3 rows: C = textscan(fileID, '%f %f %f','Delimiter',',', 'HeaderLines',3);